# Rasa chatbot : Retrieving conversation data

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to build a chatbot using RASA. For now, I am running my chatbot locally on a Ubuntu shell. I'd like to be able to retrieve my conversation data ; from RASA's documentation, it seems to be possible, but the documentation only addresses the case when the bot is running on a http server : [link](https://nlu.rasa.com/closeloop.html)

Comment: Can you point to the exact part of the documentation where it mentions it?

Comment: Are you looking to load the whole conversation history or state of the conversation?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a [Mongo or Redis tracker store](https://rasa.com/docs/core/tracker_stores/#mongotrackerstore) which stores all the conversations data in a database. Do so by adding a section like this to your endpoint configuration:

```
tracker_store:
    store_type: mongod
    url: <url to your mongo instance, e.g. mongodb://localhost:27017>
    db: <name of the db within your mongo instance, e.g. rasa>
    username: <username used for authentication>
    password: <password used for authentication>
```

Then specify this file with `--endpoints` when you run Rasa Core, e.g.

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models --endpoints endpoints.yml
```

The alternative would be to run Rasa Core with the exposed Rest API, e.g.

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models --enable-api
```

Then you can access the conversations with HTTP requests as documented [here](https://rasa.com/docs/core/server/#operation/getTracker), e.g.:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://localhost:5005/conversations/<sender_id>/tracker
```